# name of this notation for defining a set/type: e.g. $\mathbb N = 0 | \sigma \mathbb N$, or e.g. $S = 0 | 1 | SS$?

Tags: notation, terminology, formal-languages

This is a notation that I've often seen used to define sets:
To define the natural numbers: $$\mathbb N = 0 | \sigma \mathbb N,$$ which gives us $0,\sigma 0, \sigma\sigma 0, ...$

$$S = 0 | 1 | SS,$$
which gives us $0,1,00,01,10,11,000,001...$

**What is the name of this notation for recursively defining sets?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are production rules of a context-free grammar.